# What is Dickens’ “fly-catcher”?

Tags: meaning, slang, metaphors, charles-dickens

This is a passage from Dickens’ [*Little Dorrit*](https://dickens.thefreelibrary.com/Little-Dorrit/1-11#:%7E:text=Godfather%20Break%20of%20Day%20was%20peeping%20at%20its%20namesake), chapter 11. Emphasised words relate to the question below.

> ‘Ah Heaven, then,’ said she. ‘When the boat came up from Lyons, and brought the news that the devil was actually let loose at Marseilles, some **fly-catchers** swallowed it. But I? No, not I.’
>
> ‘Madame, you are always right,’ returned the tall Swiss. ‘Doubtless you were enraged against that man, madame?’
>
> ‘Ay, yes, then!’ cried the landlady, raising her eyes from her work, opening them very wide, and tossing her head on one side. ‘Naturally, yes.’
>
> ‘He was a bad subject.’
>
> ‘He was a wicked wretch,’ said the landlady, ‘and **well merited** what he had the good fortune to escape. So much the worse.’

What does the term *fly-catchers* above  mean?

Also: What does it mean to say "well merited what he had the good fortune to escape"? What is *well merited* here? The good fortune? If he was a wicked wretch then why was his escape *well merited*?.

I fail to understand the meaning of the above sentences.

Comment: It's not clear what the landlady means by _fly-catchers_, but it's a reference to people 'swallowing' (accepting) the news without question. She says that Rigaud _well deserved_ the conviction for murder which he managed to escape, apparently because the evidence against him was not considered strong enough.

Comment: It is probably a reference to the [venus flytrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venus_flytrap) -- a pun of sorts.

Comment: @HotLicks - If such tropical plants were well-known in 19th century France, which I doubt.

Comment: Since this was well before the PC age: fly catchers => frogs => the French...perhaps?

Comment: @KateBunting - There were also wasps that were referred to as "fly catchers" when I was kid.

Comment: @KillingTime - But this scene is happening _in_ France among French people!

Comment: @KateBunting I think Sven's answer is probably correct, but would a true Englishman pass up the chance for such a double entendre...?

Answer (score 8):

J.S. Farmer & W.E. Henley, [*Slang and Its Analogues, Past and Present*](https://books.google.com/books?id=xqJBAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA44&dq=%22fly-catcher%22+slang&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjf8NGM2N_2AhUDLTQIHeecBHwQ6AF6BAgJEAI#v=onepage&q=%22fly-catcher%22%20slang&f=false) (1893) has this relevant entry for *fly-catcher*:

> **FLY-CATCHER**, *subs.* ... **2.** (common). — An open-mouthed ignoramus ; a GAPESEED ["An open-mouthed loiterer"] — SYDNEY SMITH. Fr[ench] *gobe-mouche*.

Henry Smith, [*A Dictionary of Terms, Phrases, and Quotations*](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZyIMAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA233&dq=%22fly-catcher%22+slang&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjf8NGM2N_2AhUDLTQIHeecBHwQ6AF6BAgGEAI#v=onepage&q=%22fly-catcher%22%20slang&f=false) (1895) offers this further comment on *gobe-mouche*:

> **Gobe-mouche,** or **gobe-mouches.** {Fr. gober, *to gulp*, mouche, *a fly*.} **1.** The fly-catcher, a bird; hence, **2,** a silly gossip, ready to swallow any news.

Although Dickens's character uses the term *fly-catchers* rather than the semi-Anglicized *gobes-mouches*, the author seems to have in mind precisely the idea of "silly gossip[s], ready to swallow any news" that Smith applies to the term *gobe-mouche*.

The image of a credulous or stupid person as being open-mouthed and as being willing to "swallow anything" (in a figurative sense) is of long standing. If I recall correctly, Aristophanes in *The Clouds* has the character Socrates habitually walk around open mouthed and staring upward—with unpleasant results.

---

For completeness, I will simply reiterate what Kate Bunting wrote hours ago in a comment beneath the posted question: "well merited" in this context means "fully deserved." The speaker is saying that "the devil" [Rigaud] fully deserved that which he had managed to avoid by good luck—namely, punishment for his wickedness.

Comment: Well spotted, Sven!  Dickens also uses the expression _bad subject_, a literal translation of the French _mauvais sujet_ (a worthless person, a bad lot).

Comment: I didn't know the term "fly-catcher" with that meaning but took it to mean just that. The pejorative term "mouth breather" seems to me to be a modern analogue.

Comment: I think we should use well merited in a positive sense, not something we disapprove of. for example we should write he well merited the scholarship , because he is  talented.

Comment: Yes, an open-mouthed ignoramus. In that trope, the person would "swallow" everything {tout gober), which would include flies. Today, we'd say: a victim of fake news. (ahem)

Answer (score 1):

There are two literal meaning :

> 1. b. A contrivance for catching flies.
>
> 1848   Hardy in Hist. Berwickshire Naturalists' Club 2 No. 6. 321   This implement is much used in Cornwall, where it is called the ‘fly-catcher’.

The fly-catcher itself was/is, when filled with flies, a rather revolting thing.

and

> 2. A bird that catches flies; in England, usually one of the genus Muscicapa, esp. M. grisola; in America, usually one of the genus Tyrannus, T. Carolinensis or T. pipiri.

hence, in both cases, the figurative use:

**figurative.**

> 1708   P. A. Motteux Wks. F. Rabelais (1737) v. xv. 61   Ye scurvy Fly-catchers you! [i.e. lawyers].
>
> 1889   Daily News 5 Feb. 5/3   The quidnuncs* and flycatchers.

The sense is then one of a person who will collect and hold or consume bad, salacious, and sensational gossip and news regardless of how repulsive or accurate these items might be.

**A person who constantly asks: ‘What now?’; an inquisitive or nosy person; a gossip.*

Comment: Could it be the same idea as "[mouth-breather](https://www.lexico.com/definition/mouth-breather)" or "[slack-jawed yokel](https://simpsonswiki.com/wiki/Cletus,_the_Slack-Jawed_Yokel!)"?

Comment: @StuartF I think those terms connote dullness or stupidity more than the proclivity to latch onto gossip. As a practical matter, there may be some overlap in the categories.